# Typescript use enums inside json

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings

I have declared an enum like this

```js
enum Type {
  "x": "x",
  "y": "y"
}
```

and I want to store a json file like this

```js
{
 "key1": enum.x,
 "key2": enum.y
}
```

Is there any way I could use the enum value in the json file?

Comment: JSON cannot refer to variables. You can only store `"key1": "x"`, and then post-process whether `"x"` is a valid enum value.

Comment: @deceze do you recommend me some other way to store this kind of object? I wanted to make sure the data is consistent by using those enums.

Comment: you can first store the object in a variable using enum, then write it into a json file afterwards

Comment: Again, at best you can store `"x"` or `"enum.x"`. You will have to post-process that in code, e.g. something like `json.key1 = enum[json.key1]`.